# My linear layout only flashses a background color instead of persisting in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a recycler view with a list of linearlayouts that should be clickable. Once selected I want the background color to change, but I'm having trouble doing that. With the code I have right now, the selected linearlayout just flashes a color, and then reverts back to white/transparent.
How can I make it so that once it's selected, the color stays?

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listcontentlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/selector">
```

selector background drawable (the primary dark color is getting flashed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--  Active Row-->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
<!--  Pressed Row -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" /> />
```

The linear layout is inside of a recycler view for the master/detail flow as well, this is the onClick method

```
private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DummyContent.DummyItem item = (DummyContent.DummyItem) view.getTag();
            if (mTwoPane) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);
                ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                mParentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
```

Thanks! Let me know if you need more info.

(This is what [I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwTz5.png))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your onClick method of the LinearLayout set linearLayout.setSelected(true)

If you have set clicklistener to the LinearLayout then use the following snippet,

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
      view.setSelected(true)
     //Your code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! So that did work in coloring the items, but is there a way to force only one of them to be selected at a time? Because if I click a second layout, both of them are colored, and I only want one of them to be selected at a time

Comment: You have to maintain the previous selected view and call setSelected(false) if the current clicked view is not equal to the previous selected view. For the first time the previous view will be null. So, check null and call setSelected(false)